# Custom pager "Showing X - Y of Z results"

Tags: 7, theming, paging

I have some entities queried from an external solr server using custom code and Search API, and I'm listing them 10 per page.

I have created a pager for the page using `pager_default_initialize()` and `theme('pager')`.

I wanted to insert a text into the pager div that says "Showing X - Y of Z results". I can do this manually by overriding the `theme_pager()` function, but I was wondering is there a drupal native function or some setting which you can pass to theme_pager that does this?

I suppose in short I want the Views 3 equivalent of "Full pager", instead at the moment I'm only able to produce the "Mini" pager.

Answer (score 1):

In views you can use the below php function and place it in header with php filter

```
<?php
global $pager_page_array, $pager_total_items, $pager_total;
$my_view = views_get_current_view();
$items_per_page = $my_view->pager['items_per_page'];
if ($pager_total[0] == 1) {
  echo t('Showing <b>!pager_total_items</b> results',
    array('!pager_total_items' => $pager_total_items[0])
  );
} else {
  $start = 1 + ($pager_page_array[0] * $items_per_page);
  $end = (1 + $pager_page_array[0]) * $items_per_page;
  if ($end > $pager_total_items[0]) $end = $pager_total_items[0];
  echo t('Showing !start-!end of <b>!pager_total_items</b> results',
    array('!start' => $start, '!end' => $end, '!pager_total_items' => $pager_total_items[0])
  );
}
?>
```

See the below is result

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a views view, it's a custom pager on a node.

Comment: Works well, you could also add this as a variable in a hook_preprocess_views_view() and override the view's template to avoid having to use the PHP filter